# Repeat function until index value exceeds threshold in R

Tags: r

I need to apply a function until an index limit (distance, in this case) is met. I'm trying to figure out a way to apply the function repeatedly while avoiding recursion issues.

**Example:**

I want to apply the following code until `total_dist`  = `flight_distance` (2500 km). The distance traveled in a given flight depends on the energy available. The flight proceeds as a series of jumps and stops--expending and obtaining energy, respectively. If there is enough energy at the start, the flight can be finished in only two jumps (with one stop). Sometimes two or more stops are necessary. I can't know this ahead of time.

So how can I modify `jump_metrics` to get it to repeat until the total distance covered is 2500?

```
flight_distance = 2500
flight_markers = c(1:flight_distance)

TD_cost_km = rnorm(2500, 5, 1)
potential_stops = c(1:(flight_distance-1))
cumulative_flight_cost = vector("list", length=length(potential_stops))
for(i in 1:length(potential_stops)) {
  cumulative_flight_cost[[i]] = cumsum(TD_cost_km[flight_markers>potential_stops[i]])
}

max_fuel_quantiles = seq(0, 1, length=flight_distance)
jump_metrics = function() {
  start_fuel_prob = qbeta(runif(flight_distance, pbeta(max_fuel_quantiles,1,1), 
                                pbeta(max_fuel_quantiles,1,1)), 1.45*2, 1)
  start_energy_level_est = 
    rnorm(1, sample(1544 + (start_fuel_prob * 7569), 1, replace=T), 
          0.25)
  start_max_energy = ifelse(start_energy_level_est < 1544, 1544,
                            start_energy_level_est)

  fuel_level = start_max_energy - cumulative_flight_cost[[1]]
  dist_traveled = length(fuel_level[fuel_level>(max(fuel_level)*0.2)])
  dist_left = flight_distance - dist_traveled
  partial_dist = 1 + dist_traveled
  dist_dep_max_energy = c(rep(start_max_energy, length(1:dist_left)), 
                          seq(start_max_energy, 1544, 
                              length.out=length((dist_left+1):flight_distance)))

  next_max_energy = dist_dep_max_energy[partial_dist]
  next_fuel_level = next_max_energy - cumulative_flight_cost[[partial_dist]]
  next_dist_traveled = length(next_fuel_level[next_fuel_level >
                                                (max(next_fuel_level)*0.2)])
  total_dist = next_dist_traveled + partial_dist
  list(partial_dist, next_dist_traveled, total_dist)  
}
jump_metrics()
```

Comment: You can put it in a `while` loop, but I'm wary of this function not taking any inputs or seeing you assign any outputs. Seems risky to have it just rely on so many things in the global environment. Just looking at it, running it twice won't change the result, will it? So if you want to "repeat" it and get a different answer you'll need to specify what changes at each repetition.

Comment: That has concerned me too, @Gregor, perhaps I don't need a function at all. But I am still not sure how to achieve the overall goal of performing the calculations until the total distance is reached.

Comment: A function sound is great, but you should pass things into the function. And if you want it to work iteratively, one of the things you should pass in is the total_distance that you're hoping to update.